# Calculate Single Column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table as below :

```
id       jancuk        pijut
-------------------------------
1        20 * 4         
2         2 + 4         
3     3 - 1 + 2         
4        20 / 5
```

I want to update column `pijut` with result from `jancuk` column. Is this possible in oracle using query?
So, if the table has been updated, then the table should be looks like this :

```
id       jancuk        pijut
-------------------------------
1        20 * 4         80
2         2 + 4          6
3     3 - 1 + 2          4
4        20 / 5          4
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: `jancuk` is varchar? `pijut` is integer? also, how complex can the equations be?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yes, jancuk = varchar and pijut = number (10,0)

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but something very close to one in this blog entry (by Tom Kyte). http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2010/04/evaluating-expression-like-calculator.html

Comment: where you got this requirement ?? is this scenario exists in real time

Comment: Thanks @dmansfield. But is this possible without stored procedure?

Comment: @Jonathan Column `PIJUT` will updated every month. So until the end of every month, the table could be has many rows with PIJUT = NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
update tbl
set "pijut" = xmlquery(replace( "jancuk", '/', ' div ' ) returning content ).getNumberVal();
```

For more info [link](http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2010/04/evaluating-expression-like-calculator.html)

Comment: Thanks Praven, but I got this error : `[Err] ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: can not get jancuk string`

Comment: Zacurned Ace, try to remove double quotes from query

Comment: do you have any `null` value in the column `jancuk`

Comment: Yes, Now it works when I exclude null column for jancuk. This take a lot of execution time, but it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use function with dynamic SQL to do that -

```
create or replace function calc_value(str in varchar2) return number is
 val_ number;
begin
    if str is null then
         return null;
    end if;
    execute immediate 'begin :val_ := '||str||'; end;' using out val_;
    return val_;
end;
/
```

and result select will be -

```
with t as
(
select 1 as id, '        20 * 4 ' as jancuk from dual union all
select 2 as id, '         2 + 4 ' as jancuk from dual union all      
select 3 as id, '     3 - 1 + 2 ' as jancuk from dual union all       
select 4 as id, '        20 / 5 ' as jancuk from dual
)
select id, jancuk, calc_value(jancuk) as pijut
from t
```

Comment: Can I execute dynamic SQL in single query without function?

Comment: Yes, there are given other answers. This is just one solution among many.

Comment: I tried this. `update tbl set pijut = calc_value(jancuk)` and give me this error : `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`

Comment: I updated my answer. Its work fine in your sample data, if you have other expression in your talbe you can edit procedure adding the necessary checks.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the answer.